# What do you call an electronic switch that maps from some configurable subset of inputs to one output?

Tags: switches, identification, components, multiplexer, switching

Analog multiplexers are N x 1; they select one input from a set of inputs and route it to one output.

Analog crosspoint switches are N x M; they select various subsets of inputs and route them to one or more outputs, basically being an N x M SPST array.

Is there a name for an IC which is N x 1, but can select any *subset* of inputs and sum them to the output? So like a multiplexer, but in which you can select multiple inputs simultaneously (preferably doing a buffered sum).

Is this something which some multiplexers can do, or is there another name for this kind of thing? It seems to basically be like a "nonblocking" analog crosspoint switch but where you only use one output.

Comment: Seems like a pile of AND/OR gates. AND each input signal with its 'enable' bit, then OR all the resulting values together.

Comment: For analog signals, it'd be a crosspoint switch followed by a summing amplifier. I don't think this is likely to exist as a single component. Unless you made it in an FPAA, I suppose...

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you may want to shoot an e-mail to Analog Linear Devices.  They might know the component you are looking for.  Basically, you seem to be looking for an array of Op-Amps that can be configured so that each input can be part of an Add-function or not.  Sounds like a job for a microcontroller anyway.  Have the controller do the additions after analog reads and then analog out.
From ALD just as a search term:
EPAD stands for Electrically Programmable Analog Device. It is a new classification of analog integrated circuits developed by Advanced Linear Devices.

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting - what is the difference between an FPAA and an EPAD?

Comment: A "mixing desk" perhaps?